# Apache poi cast cell value to object

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

Hello i need to case my cell value to object type but i get error :

```
 the method setRfpid(rfpobject) in the type AspsortObject is not applicable for the arguments (capture#1-of ? extends Cell)
```

my code is :

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
 public void addaspsort(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException
 { 
     ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0);        
     FileInputStream f =  (FileInputStream) file.getInputStream();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(f); 
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
        Row row;
        for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){ 
             row = sheet.getRow(i);
             rfpobject rfpid = new rfpobject();
             AspsortObject aspsort =  new AspsortObject();
             aspsort.setRfpid( row.getCell(0).getClass().cast(rfpid));
             aspsort.setRequestid(row.getCell(1).toString());
```

}}

my classe is  :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aspsortobject")
public class AspsortObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private rfpobject rfpid;
    private String requestid;
    private String aspart;
    private String aspname;
    private String asporganisation;
    private String aspsort;
```

please what i should to do to get my cell value with the type object because the object is foreign key in by datavase

Comment: Why do you want to turn it into an Object? Why not get the value as a String or a Number or a Date or whatever?

Comment: because  i need to respect the relation manytoone in my class and i have Class Type so what i should to do to resolve this error please :!

Comment: What is `rfpobject`? There would must be a constructor to create a new `rfpobject` from values in column `A` of your Excel sheet. Something like `aspsort.setRfpid( new rfpobject(...row.getCell(0).get...));` where `...` depends on what constructors exists for rfpobject. Or `rfpobject` would must have a member of type `String`, `Number`, or `Date` and a setter for that member. Then `rfpobject rfpid = new rfpobject(); rfpid.set...(row.getCell(0).get...); ... aspsort.setRfpid(rfpid );`. Btw.: `rfpobject` is bad named. It should start uppercase to follow the name conventions.

Comment: hello i get this error  : org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.pfe.backend.models.AspsortObject.rfpid -> com.pfe.backend.models.Rfpobject

Comment: so i resolve  this error ": object references an unsaved transient instance"   using CascadeTYPE.Persist but the foreign key in my database is null please what i should to do